# What compiler would I use to write machine language?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

Just out of interested I would like to write a small program in machine code.

I am currently learning about registers, ALU, buses and memory and I'm slightly fascinated that instructions can be written in binary instead an assembly language.

Would a compiler would need to be used?

Preferably one that runs on OSX.

Comment: If you're writing "machine code", you don't need a compiler because there's nothing to compile.

Comment: @Riess, you should probably report your issue to meta.stackoverflow.com ...

Comment: Thanks bdonlan. I am reporting now.

Comment: @riess - email team@stackoverflow.com and the dev team will look into the reason why you can't mark questions as accepted.

Comment: This has reminded me of Turbo Pascal 3, where `Inline` took hex-represented machine code (and interspersed variable names, IIRC). Thankfully, later versions of Turbo Pascal accepted assembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would not use a compiler to write raw machine code. You would use a hex editor. Unfortunately, I don't use OSX, so I can't provide you a specific link to one.

If you write machine code, you will need to learn how to write the binary headers required by your OS as well. I would recommend doing so and testing with an assembler in raw output format first; once you understand the binary layout it is a purely mechanical task to hand-assemble this to machine code.

Comment: I use HexFiend ( http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/ ) and it does the job for me on the MacBook.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a hex editor. I recommend instead of doing that though, learn assembler first. Assembler is basically a language with a 1:1 correspondence between human readable mnemonics and the machine readable hex bytes. For that, you would probably like to look at http://ref.x86asm.net/ and find an assembler that works on x86 Macs. I believe [yasm](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/) should work.

Writing anything directly in hex is extremely difficult, and your time would probably be spent learning assembly and the underlying machine code that an assembler generates

Comment: I am currently learning assembler. I am also reading "Inside The Machine". It got me a little interested.

Comment: @Riess good then. I recommend finding a good hex editor and looking at the generated machine code, as well as using a disassembler to test your own modifications/creations in machine code. This is probably the easiest way of learning machine code.. I wrote an 8086 emulator and the only machine code I have memorized is 0xF4 is hlt and 0x90 is nop

Comment: Thats a good idea. For years I've heard of hex editors, I've actually played with them, but I've never understood their real purpose. Just a quick question, why is the convention to use hex and not binary? Is it something to do with the memory 2-bytes to 1 hexadecimal number?

Comment: @Riess hex is just very easy to work with because each digit is 4 bits, so rather than writing 10001111 you can just write 8F. In some circles, Octal is preferred rather than hex in which each digit is 3 bits. This isn't used very often now though because you can't easily put in just 1 byte of information

Comment: After looking at binary code for a few minutes, you will become bit-blind and you will be unable to tell one pattern from another.  It's just the way our eyes/brain work - fantastic at recognising faces across a crowded bar, hopeless for repeating patterns of just two symbols.  The same hapens with hex representations, but it takes much longer before you read $0F as $F0 :)

Comment: @Martin James: you will just read it as `DF`, and `8F` as `BF`.

Comment: @Martin James: You could have fun with binary though and draw some faces like with ASCII art and then see what happens when you run it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need an assembler, you really do, as other posters have said  Writing binary instruction codes is so mind-numbingly boring, and has to be so correct, that only a machine should do it.  On a non-trivial OS, like OSX. Linux, Windows, the correct header information must be supplied to generate an executable file.  Again, this is best done by an assembler package that can link the correct headers in to ensure that you have data, stack and execution for your instructions.  Then, your assembler program will crash, and again, and again, for ages :D.

Writing binary instructions is usually classed as torture.  Doing it violates basic human rights.  If you are ever asked to do it, outsource it to Gitmo.

Get an assembler.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

A compiler turns your non-machine code into machine code... so you would not need a compiler...

Comment: @Riess Howder: Yeah, I read the rest and deleted the NASM reference.  Not sure why you think you would need a compiler if you are writing machine code though...

Comment: I did actually question that as I was writing the question.

Comment: @Riess Howder: It sounds like you really just want to know how to load your native program.  The first step you will take is studying the processor documentation.  Learn how instructions work, what each byte/section of an instruction means, etc.  I would however strongly suggest learning assembler instead though.  Assembler is simply a set of mnemonics for machine instructions and you will save yourself a lot of time and headache while still learning how the CPU works.

Comment: I am learning assembler. I was reading "Inside the Machine" and he got me interested in machine code because I understood it pretty well.

Comment: @Riess Howder: I'm with you on this. I wanted to know a bit about machine code too and found it fascinating. You won't want to do it for long though but it is a bit of a kick. I found www.easy68k.com is good for showing the assembly and hex side by side although it's obviously motorola 68000 and not intel x86 but I'm sure there are plenty of equivalents for that processor family. In fact you could use debug in DOS to write a simple .COM program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your machine-code inside a standard object file, with metadata so you can link it with and call it from a C program, **you'd probably still want to use an assembler.**

Besides object-file metadata, this gives you the huge advantage of being able to write comments.  And also labels to get the assembler to calculate displacements for [manual jump encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) like `db 0xE8` ; `dd  target - ($ + 4)` to encode an x86 `jmp rel32`.  Or for RIP-relative addressing modes.

---

Assembler source code usually uses mnemonics like `add eax, ecx` to assemble the bytes `01 c8` into the output file (x86).  But that source line is exactly equivalent to NASM-syntax `db 0x01, 0xc8` (assuming BITS 32 or BITS 64), or with GAS syntax `.byte 0x01, 0xc8`.

Either way, those source lines will cause the assembler to output the same 2 bytes into the current section of the output file.  That's what assemblers do: write bytes into an output file based on some text source.  asm source is a convenient language that maps pretty directly to/from machine code.  For x86, the assembler has a few choices to make, to pick the shortest encoding, and choose one of two possible opcodes e.g. between `add r/m32, r32` vs. `add r32, r/m32` when both operands are registers.

Since you're on MacOS, NASM isn't the most reliable choice.  It's had multiple bugs in its MachO64 output format support.  AFAIK the current version works, but you might rather use the GNU assembler (which OS X's default compiler, clang, can assemble).

OTOH, NASM does have a convenient flat-binary output mode which you can use to get *just* the machine code byte without the object file around them, without having to use `objcopy` into a flat binary or `ld`.

You can write `int add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }` in asm for x86-64 MacOS like this.  ([MacOS prepends C names with a leading underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763624/cant-link-an-assembly-file-s-with-gcc-on-macos-sierra))

```
;section .text        ; already the default if you haven't use section .data or anything

; NASM syntax:
global _add                    ; externally visible symbol name for linking
_add:
    lea   eax, [rdi+rsi]
    ret
```

We can assemble this with `nasm -fmacho64 mac-add.asm`, and get a 238-byte `mac-add.o` output file.  We can get a byte-for-byte identical output file from writing the bytes with `db` directives / pseudo-instructions.  But first, lets cheat and find out what the bytes were, so we don't waste time looking at tables up the encoding manually.

(Once you know the basics of how x86 machine code instructions are put together, with prefixes, opcode, ModRM + optional extra bytes, then optional immediate, you'll find it usually uninteresting to look up the actual opcode numbers; the interesting thing is usually just instruction *length*.  **Or anything you're curious about, you can look at in the disassembly output.**)

For example, [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base) and [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation/53976236#53976236) give some details about instruction encoding.  Understanding how these work is sufficient to have a pretty good idea of x86 machine code without actually knowing the specific numbers for lots of instructions.

```
$ objdump -d -Mintel mac-add.o
  (doesn't support MachO64 object files on my Linux desktop)
$ llvm-objdump -d -x86-asm-syntax=intel mac-add.o

mac-add.o:      file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:
_add:
       0:       8d 04 37        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
       3:       c3      ret
```

So in NASM source, `mac-raw-add.asm`:

```
global _add
_add:                     ; we're still letting the assembler make object-file metadata
  db 0x8d, 0x04, 0x37     ; lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  db 0xc3                 ; ret
```

**Assembling this with the same `nasm -fmacho64` makes a byte-for-byte identical object file.  `cmp mac-*.o` prints no output and returns true.**  You could link it with a C program with `clang -O2 -g main.c mac-raw-add.o`.

---

#### Silly computer tricks with machine code

One of the fun things you can do in machine code but not asm is have an instruction overlap other instructions, e.g. enter a loop 4 bytes in with the 1-byte opcode for `cmp eax, imm32` instead of 2-byte `jmp rel8`.  But this is only useful for "code golf" (optimizing for code-size at the expense of everything else, including performance).

Modern CPUs don't like it when they have to decode some code bytes from a different start point than they already decoded from.  Some AMD CPUs mark instruction boundaries in L1i cache.  I forget if/why Intel CPUs would have a problem.  I'm not sure if it would conflict in the uop cache; [Agner Fog's microarch guide says for Sandybridge](https://agner.org/optimize/) "*The same piece of code can have multiple entries in the μop cache if it has multiple jump entries.*", but IDK if that works for different decoding of the same bytes.

Anyway, you can do crazy stuff like:

```
global _copy_nonzero_ints
_copy_nonzero_ints:      ;; void f(int *dst, int *src)

   xor  edx, edx
   db 0x3d       ; opcode for cmp eax, imm32.  Consumes the next 4 bytes as its immediate
   ;;   BAD FOR PERFORMANCE, DON'T DO THIS NORMALLY
.loop:                        ; do {
    mov  [rdi + rdx*4 - 4], eax    ; 4 bytes long: opcode + ModRM + SIB + disp8.  Skipped on first loop iteration: decoded as the immediate for cmp
    mov  eax, [rsi + rdx*4]
    inc  edx                       ; only works for array sizes < 4 * 4GB
    test eax, eax
    jnz  .loop                ; }while(src[i] != 0)

    ret
```

Notice that we have the loop-branch at the bottom like we want, but we load and test a dword before storing it.  This hypothetical loop doesn't want to store the terminating `0` dword.  Normally you'd `jmp` into the loop to a label, or peel the load+test from the first iteration to conditionally jump over the loop, or fall into the loop to store the first element if it should run non-zero times.  ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump))

The first time through the loop, it decodes as

```
   0:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
   2:   3d 89 44 97 fc          cmp    eax,0xfc974489
   7:   8b 04 96                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsi+rdx*4]
   a:   ff c2                   inc    edx
   c:   85 c0                   test   eax,eax
   e:   75 f3                   jne    3 <_copy_nonzero_ints+0x3>

(from yasm -felf64 foo.asm  && objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.o
 YASM doesn't create visible symbol-table entries for .label local labels
 NASM does even if you don't specify extra debug info)
```

After the first `jnz` is taken, it decodes as:

```
0000000000000000 <_copy_nonzero_ints>:
   0:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
   2:   3d                      .byte 0x3d

0000000000000003 <_copy_nonzero_ints.loop>:
   3:   89 44 97 fc             mov    DWORD PTR [rdi+rdx*4-0x4],eax
   7:   8b 04 96                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsi+rdx*4]
   a:   ff c2                   inc    edx
   c:   85 c0                   test   eax,eax
   e:   75 f3                   jne    3 <_copy_nonzero_ints.loop>
  10:   c3                      ret
```

Also works with things like `db 0xb9, 0x7b` : first 2 bytes of `mov ecx, 123` which consumes next 3 as the high bytes of the immediate.  Leaves CL with a known value, the high bytes of ECX are dependent on the 3 bytes of code.  If you can find instructions that have the encoding you want, you might actually be able to use your code as useful immediate data instead.

---

The above loop was just a made up example to illustrate a possible use-case for that trick.  It's *not* the most efficient way to implement that function; you'd probably use `lodsd` and `stosd` if actually golfing for code-size.

Also, this is pretty slow vs. using SSE2 to copy + check 4 dwords at a time, so you wouldn't normally write this anyway for performance.  **But imagine you're optimizing for code size.  (and see [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code)**)

Also, you might index the src relative to the dst, like `sub rsi, rdi` before the loop, so you can use `add rdi, 4` inside the loop, with `mov [rdi-4], eax` stores (which can run on port 7 on Intel so this is more hyperthreading-friendly), and `mov eax, [rsi+rdi]` loads.