# Can't link an assembly file (.s) with GCC on macOS Sierra

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly

I have 2 files to compile.
The first is main.c and the 2nd is a function that does sums and multiplications in assembly (work.s).

This is the code :

**main.c file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

short work(); 

int main() {

    short z = work();
    printf("work(); -> %hd\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

**work.s file:**

```
.globl work;

work :

    xorl %eax,%eax;
    xorl %ecx,%ecx;
    movw $20,%ax;
    subw $2,%ax;
    movw $7,%cx;
    addw $3,%cx;
    movw $10,%cx;
    subw $3,%cx;
    shl $1,%cx;
    addw %cx,%ax;
    ret;
```

From command line using gcc : `gcc -m32 main.c work.s -o main`

This is the output :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_work", referenced from:
>         _main in main-fbbcca.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

While on Linux with same files and commands it works, why and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe change your global to the name gcc is looking for?

```
.globl _work;

_work :
       ...
```

There are other approaches, too:

https://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Code/Asm.and.C/C-asm/Asm-C-example0.shtml

<= Different compiler, same principles...

Comment: It works thank you,I'm studying assembly for an exam and my prof explained it in this way on Linux so I have to follow his approach but I'll keep it in mind :).

Comment: @feded Linux and macOS have different symbol decoration schemes. That's why you need an underscore on macOS but not on Linux.

Comment: @feded: tuz is correct.  Different platforms and different compilers simply have different "symbol decoration schemes".  Look here for further discussion: [Why do C compilers prepend underscores to external names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627511/).

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks,I didn't know that but however I don't understand why Mac needs of underscore in .s files and Linux doesn't  .

Comment: It's not just "macOS vs. Linux".  *ANY* combination of platform (e.g. Windows vs. BSD) or compiler (e.g. gcc vs. CLang) can "do it differently".  FYI, gcc lets you control the behavior with `-fleading-underscore` and `-fnoleading-underscore` compiler switches: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

Answer (score 2):

In `work.s`, change `work` to `_work` both places it appears. The compiler prefixes an underscore to C names. Assembly language is more bare bones, so you have to prefix the underscore yourself.

Comment: I wrote < stdio.h > because if I write it without space it disappear and the #includes  becomes INCLUDES in bold, don't know why.My code is #include <stdio.h>.